# Android - set app theme (style)

Tags: java, android, styles, themes

I currently on my app I had the theme set to the default of the device

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
```

And then I have noticed this theme being used more and more and really like it and see that it is the device default on some devices, and would like to set this theme for my app I have been searching for it but can't find it. It is the theme with this back button.

[image]

Where can I find this/ set it as me theme,

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to get the material design theme on a non lollipop device. To use the theme you need to use the android the compatibility library. Import: `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` into your activity, then change: `public class MyClass extends Activity` to: `public class MyClass extends ActionBarActivity`. You'll need to install the support library through the SDK manager and import it with gradle. More info on the library can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html). You want v7 of the library not v4.

Your style should look something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/color2</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/color3</item>
    <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/color1</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/color1</item>
</style>
```

Put that style in your: `values-v21/styles.xml` and replace the colors with your colors.

You can read more [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Comment: will i also put the is the non -v21 styles.xml? so it will work with older versions of android?

Comment: The AppCompat material theme will work on on older versions. The colors will not.